# Copy Files don't begin with number char in Batch

Tags: batch-file

how to copy files without begin number char in batch files

for example my Dir list its:

```
12red.pcx
9red.pcx
96blue.pcx
alipro.pcx
```

then i need only copy alipro.pcx by batch

use this batch code for copy files begin with number char:

```
@echo off
set Design_path=D:\
set USB_path=E:\usb\
set t12=12*.pcx
set t9=9*.pcx
set t6=6*.pcx
set tsize=*.pcx
set design12=Dis_12
set design9=Dis_9
set design6=Dis_6
set designsize=D_Size
rem // Create Dir if not exist
if not exist %Design_path%%design12% (mkdir %Design_path%%design12%) 
if not exist %Design_path%%design9% (mkdir %Design_path%%design9%) 
if not exist %Design_path%%design6% (mkdir %Design_path%%design6%) 
if not exist %Design_path%%designsize% (mkdir %Design_path%%designsize%) 
if exist %USB_path%%t12% copy %USB_path%%t12% %Design_path%%design12%
if exist %USB_path%%t9% copy %USB_path%%t9% %Design_path%%design9%
if exist %USB_path%%t6% copy %USB_path%%t6% %Design_path%%design6%
```

Comment: How is your code related to your requirements? As for the req. I'd use `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.pcx^|findstr "^[^0-9]" ') Do Echo copy %%A x:\whereever`

Comment: Just saw that `%%a` has erroneously different casing - change them to be equal either upper or lower case.

Comment: @LotPings i need copy any file except files begin with 9,6 and 12 number . this code dont work:    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir %USB_path% /b *.pcx^|findstr /r /c:"^[^6][^6][^12]" ') do (
    echo %%a
    copy "%USB_path%%%a" "%Design_path%%designsize%"
  )

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses findstr's limited RegEx capabilities to select only lines
beginning (`^` anchors at begin) with a negated character class `[^]` which are not 
zero to nine `[^0-9]`

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
  'dir /B *.pcx^|findstr "^[^0-9]" '
) Do Echo copy %%a x:\whereever
```

If you want to exclude special numbers you can do with a different RegEx which 
filters lines ***not*** matching with the option `/V`
You can have several RegEx separated with a SPACE

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
  'dir /B "*.pcx" ^|findstr /V "^6 ^9 ^12" '
) Do (
  Echo %%a
  Rem copy ...
)
```

Sample output

```
> Dir /B
11foo.pcx
12red.pcx
13bar.pcx
3366.pcx
96blue.pcx
9red.pcx
alipro.pcx

> SO_44875749.cmd
11foo.pcx
13bar.pcx
3366.pcx
alipro.pcx
```

Answer (score 0):

now for copy any file without start in number 9 , 6 , 12

for example my list its:

```
3366.pcx
12gun.pcx
9ghost2.pcx
6bgre.pcx
avf.pcx
```

i need only copy avf.pcx and 3366.pcx .

This my Code

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir %USB_path% /b *.pcx^|findstr /r /c:"^[^9][^6][^12]" ') do (
    echo %%a
    copy "%USB_path%%%a" "%Design_path%%designsize%"
  )
```

Comment: [tag:lotpings] please help me

Comment: So different from your first requirement you want to exclude specified numbers not all? BTW better edit your question and only answer your own question if you have a solution other might be interested in.

Comment: See my own answer